# Ignore string using regex

Tags: java, regex

I'm having list of strings like below

```
core.advsearch.smartshow.event
tpymt.pay.distaxdtls.event
```

I know that I can match this pattern using `Pattern.compile(".*.\\s*.\\.event");`
But I want to eliminate `.*.event` and replace with `.xml`

How to do that with regex?

**My Expected output is** :

```
core.advsearch.xml
tpymt.pay.xml
```

**PS: these strings are dynamic**

Comment: `replaceAll("\\.event", ".xml");`?

Comment: upvoting the comment above. Did you check String API docs?

Comment: Why not just `str.replace(".event", ".xml");`

Comment: @R9J: What is your expected output for your example input?

Comment: @anubhava `str.replace(".event", ".xml");` will replace the string which are known. but how would you do for a dynamic string before `.event`? I want that string to be eliminated too.

Comment: I have suggested you to provide expected output for your example input to make things clear.

Comment: And I provided you an answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
str = str.replaceAll("[^.]+\\.event", "xml");
```

#### [RegEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/mA4xE5/1)

For your input text it will produce this output:

```
core.advsearch.xml
tpymt.pay.xml
```

Comment: thanks your method worked! could you explain what `[^.]` will do?

Comment: Yes sure, `[^.]` is negation pattern to match anything but a literal dot. And `[^.]+` will match 1 or more of any character except dot. So in short `[^.]+\\.event` matches `smartshow.event` in your first string.

Answer (score 1):

The below code would replace the substring `.event` with `.xml`

```
String [] s = {  "core.advsearch.smartshow.event",
        "tpymt.pay.distaxdtls.event"};
for(String s2 : s)
{
System.out.println(s2.replaceAll("\\.event", ".xml"));
}
```

Output:

```
core.advsearch.smartshow.xml
tpymt.pay.distaxdtls.xml
```

OR

```
String [] s = {  "core.advsearch.smartshow.event",
        "tpymt.pay.distaxdtls.event"};
for(String s2 : s)
{
System.out.println(s2.replaceAll("\\.[^.]*\\.event$", ".xml"));
}
```

Output:

```
core.advsearch.xml
tpymt.pay.xml
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use regex for matching the last word in your String

**sample:**

```
String s = "core.advsearch.smartshow.event";
System.out.println(s.replaceAll("(\\.event)$", ".xml"));
```

Now the above regex will only match the last word, so lets say your string is like this: `core.advsearch.event.smartshow.event` now the first event wont get replaced with `.xml` only the last part of it.

Comment: @MarounMaroun roger that.

Comment: thanks for your answer, i want to eliminate the wildcard string just before `.event` too

Comment: @R9J can you provide a sample.